# Show more than 20 categories on highcharts heatmap xaxis

Tags: highcharts, heatmap, categories

I am working with Highcharts heatmaps. 
I have multiple data points (I am calling them functions), each having some data series defined as

The format of the above is

string, epochtime, value

The series1 or series2 (see comment below) are series names associated with each function. I want to update the series in the chart based on the click of a button associated with a function. There are multiple such functions and each function has its own button. Clicking on the button populates the respective data in the heatmap using the above array of arrays.

Th problem is when I click on adding a function which has more than 20 series defined in the format above, it doesn’t work . The screen displays time since 1970(for some reason). While it works for less than 20 series.

Comment: Function1-Dataseries=[
[‘series1name’, 1531558800000,0],
[‘series2name, 1531558800000, 2.45],
[‘series1name’, 153155940000,5.45],
[‘series2name, 153155940000, 8.45],
.
.
.

Comment: Could you share some code with us please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my bad. Apparently had to disable the turbothreshold for the heatmap via the plotOptions. Everything worked fine and i could have as many categories in the x axis.